# convert from pdf and word to images

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

The requirement is to show the thumbnail of all documents like pdf and ms-words, we are storing the documents in database, we need to convert it into file stream and have to display as thumbnail images.

As of now I am able to display image, since it is straight forward, likewise i will have to display the images of pdf and word documents.
I will show how i am doing for images

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult File(int id)
 {
      var fileToRetrieve = db.File.Find(id);
      return File(fileToRetrieve.Content, fileToRetrieve.ContentType);
 }
```

View:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
       <div class="form-group">
            <img src="~/Home/File?id=@item.FileId" alt="avatar"           width="100px" height="100x" />
       </div>
 }
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: You are asking how to print/render documents or generate thumbnails from the documents that support it. The code you posted has nothing to do with this. Have you tried anything? Have you tried googling on how to generate thumbnails, or print to an image?

Answer (score 0):

You need ImageMagick and GhostScript

```
<?php
$im = new imagick('file.pdf[0]');
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $im;
?>
```

The [0] means page 1.